# Function that opens a file for reading and returns the number of bytes and newlines

Tags: python

I currently working my way through a free online python school. The following template has been given to me, and I am to complete the function so that it returns the size of the file (number of bytes) and the number of newlines ("\n"). I'm completely stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def readFile(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    size = 0
    lines = 0
    buf = f.read()     
    while buf!="":



        buf = f.read() 

    f.close()                 

    return (size, lines)
```

Comment: Ugh. Python 'school' not using `with`. xD

Comment: It's probably a very early exercise and they don't want to confuse the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `buf` variable contains a chunk of data.

Since you are still learning I will use a very basic approach:

```
nl_count = 0  # Number of new line characters
tot_count = 0  # Total number of characters
for character in buf:
    if character == '\n':
         nl_count += 1
    tot_count += 1
```

Now you will have to adjust this to fit to your code, but this should give you something to start with.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Can i also just ask, what is the significance of "buf = f.read()" contained in the while loop? Thanks

Comment: The reading ends at `EOF`. You could set a buffer size by doing: `buf=f.read(buffer_size)`. I speak under correction, but there might be a default value here and you might hit that default before reaching `EOF` in very big files. (So you would want to read the rest inside the loop)

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the lines in at once and use the list rather than the file itself. For example,

```
def readFile(filename="test.txt"):

  f = open(filename)

  # Read all lines in at once
  buf = f.readlines()
  f.close()

  # Each element of the list will be a new line
  lines = len(buf)

  # The total of the total of each line
  size = sum([len(i) for i in buf])

  return (size, lines)
```

Comment: However, such a method will fail with very large files. Besides, the school gave a template to use, and this doesn't use it.